# Is there a way to force the selection i.e., not allowing to enter free text in the TypeAHead component?

Tags: typeahead, react-bootstrap-typeahead

For react-bootstrap-typeahead, Is there a way to force the selection from the drop-down i.e., not allowing to enter free text in the TypeAHead component?

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you're trying to make the typeahead work more like a `select` field. If so, there are a few pieces to that.You can make the input read-only to disable typing. You'll also want to change the filtering so that all the options appear in the menu, even when there is a selection:

```
<Typeahead
  ...
  filterBy={(option, state) => {
    if (state.selected.length) {
      return true;
    }
    return option.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(state.text.toLowerCase()) > -1;
  }}
  inputProps={{
    readOnly: true,
  }}
/>
```

That should get you most of the way there, though you might want to add some additional styling to make the read-only input look more interactive.

Here's a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/rbt-select-example-nfc5q?file=/src/index.js